# Eigenvalues of sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, sparse-matrices

I want to calculate the eigenvector corresponding to the $0$ eigenvalue of a large, sparse singular matrix. However, if I try `eigs(A,1,'smallestabs')`, MATLAB has an issue due to it being singular. For smaller matrices, `eig` works fine, but I need something that will work with larger matrices. Is there any way I can get `eigs` to work with this?

I'm open to other languages/ writing my own algorithm if need be as well.

Comment: If the matrix is large and sparse, presumably $0$ is an eigenvalue of high multiplicity. So you would get a multidimensional eigenspace not just an eigenvector.

Comment: Since you're looking for the $0$-eigenvalue eigenvector, you're actually after the nullspace.  Have you tried using `null(A)`?